# Linux 'mail' command: Can't open display

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron, email

I've just installed the 'mail' command in Ubuntu (mailutils package) in order to
view feedback from cron jobs.

I type 'mail' at the prompt and see something like this:

```
"/var/mail/*$USER*": 1 message 1 unread
>U 1 *Name* *Date* Output from your job
```

I type `1` at the `?` prompt and get a lot of output about the message (From, Date, Subject...) but on the last line it says

```
Error: Can't open display:
?
```

and I'm returned to the prompt.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: What is your `PAGER` variable set to?

Comment: I find it strange that X windows wants to run when you're in 'mail.' mail is a command line tool. 

You might consider using mutt to view the mail instead.

Comment: @jordanm I'm pretty sure that's what's happening. Please write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mail` program opens emails in a pager. The environment variable `PAGER` can override the default pager, which is typically `less`. In Debian-based systems, there is a `/usr/bin/pager` that is managed by the alternatives system. You need to ensure that your pager is not a GUI application, which would require X. An easy way to test this is to set `PAGER` temporarily.

```
PAGER=/usr/bin/less mail
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! Apparently i didn't have a PAGER variable in the environment, I'll add that line to my .bashrc

Comment: @ryan221b the PAGER environment variable is only required if your system does not provide a sensible default. See: `update-alternatives --list pager`

Comment: I have /bin/less /bin/more and /usr/bin/pg, but apparently I can only read the mail if I set PAGER

Answer (score -1):

it looks like trying to open GUI. you can set the your DISPLAY variable to where you are running the xwindows server to open it:

```
  export DISPLAY=IP/Hostname:0.0
```

IP/Hostname=addres to your xwindows server

Comment: That's highly unlikely to help. Most of the time, if you can display on an X server, `DISPLAY` is already set appropriately.

Comment: I normally get this error when display is not set properly. How do you know display is already set appropriately?

Comment: My point is that if `DISPLAY` isn't set appropriately, in most circumstances, setting the environment variable won't help. For example, over SSH, you need to tunnel X traffic, which automatically causes the variable to be set appropriately. Most setups run X servers that don't accept TCP connections, so setting `DISPLAY` to `$HOST:$NUM` wouldn't help.

Comment: That's right. It may not help. ryan221b may need to try to run xclock for troubleshooting to see if display is working then try to run this program.

Comment: My display is working fine: I'm using the terminal from Ubuntu's graphical desktop, Unity.